# HTMLInputElemet or webbrowser.document on Windows Phone App Login

Tags: authentication, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, windows-phone, html-input

Hey I'm try to make a Windows Phone app that logs people in to a webpage, but I'm having trouble getting the app to post the log-in info to the webbrowser.

on the desktop I would have used

```
           HTMLInputElement nameBox = (HTMLInputElement) myDoc.all.item("name", 0);
           HTMLInputElement passBox = (HTMLInputElement) myDoc.all.item("pass", 0);

       nameBox.value = "textBox1.text";
           passBox.value = "textBox2.text;
```

but the HTMLInputElemet don't exist in Windows Phone.

I also tried using webBrowser1.document but that don't work either on Windows Phone.
It is a log-in using a form and not a query string.

The server side code look like this:

```
    <div class="form-item textfield edit-name">
      <div class="label">
      <label >E-mail-adresse</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="60" placeholder="" name="name" id="edit-name" size="60" value="" class="form-text required" />  </div>
<div class="form-item password edit-pass">
      <div class="label">
      <label >Adgangskode</label>
    </div>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="edit-pass"  maxlength="128"  size="60"  class="form-text required" />  </div>
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-b6cb750ff3a79c34d408df98d730a39e" value="form-b6cb750ff3a79c34d408df98d730a39e"  />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-user-login" value="user_login"  />
<div class="form-actions"><input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Log ind"  class="form-submit" />
```

It is easy in the desktop but I just cant figure out how to do this on the Phone, hope some one can help.

Comment: yes sorry maybe I should have been more specific WP is Windows Phone :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to access the fields is using Javascript, thanks to the `InvokeScript` method:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value='{0}'", "PutTheLoginHere"));
```

Comment: That is brilliant thank you very much.. :-) is there also a way to use Javascript to do a buttonclick on the login button with the name op

Comment: @9koni Just add a `document.forms[0].submit();` to your script

Comment: Thank you that does indeed click the button but strangely i get an error from the server saying the fields are empty, but if i manually click the button after having passed in the info from the scripts it work.. I just used                  webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value='{0}'", emailBox.text));
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value='{0}'", passBox.text));
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.forms[0].submit()"));

Comment: Strang thing if i run the script 2 times it works... No idea why.. :-) but thank you very much for the help KooKiz you are a star..

Comment: @9koni You should put everything in the same script. `webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value='{0}'; document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value='{1}'; document.forms[0].submit();", emailBox.text, passBox.Text));`